# Unable to connect to Remote powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Im trying to connect to remote powershell,I have tried to authenticate it using Kerberos and negotiate both ended up the same error

A specified authentication package is unknown. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.|
This is the error message that im receiving,I need the soltution to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Start PowerShell with the Run as administrator option
- Run the following command: `Start-Service WinRM`
- Re-run the command that generated the error:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.3